# Python locals() and globals() are the same?

Tags: python, namespaces

I am messing around with local and global namespaces a bit, and i found a bit of a weird behaviour. If i do this...

```
len(globals().keys())

len(locals().keys())
```

I get two different results, first i get 344 and then i get 346. So for curiosity sake i want to know which keys are in my local but not on my global, so i do this.

```
[key for key in local().keys() if key not in globals().keys()]
```

And bam, nothing, returns a empty list.

Thinking maybe my code is faulty i try this.

```
g = [1,2,3,4]

l = [1,2,3,4,5,6]

[key for key in l if key not in g]
```

and returns as expected `[5,6]`

So, what's the reason that Python can't difference in the keys of locals() and globals().

Does it have to do with `locals() == globals()` and viceversa?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: It's probably more to do with the fact that you aren't using it right. I need more code to be able to know why the are the same thing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That is because in that case you are calling `locals` in the `global` scope. Whereas `locals` gets values in the current scope, `globals` returns all values in the `global` scope. This means that if you call `locals` in the `global` scope they will be the same. The difference is found when you call `locals` in a scope that is not `global`, for example; put that list comprehension (which is OK but for a few modifications) of yours into a function:

```
>>> def example(a, b, c):
...     return [k for k in locals().keys() if k not in globals()]
... 

>>> example(1, 2, 3)
['a', 'c', 'b']
```

So, in conclusion: yes, `locals() == globals()`- but only at the module level.

Comment: Great, that makes sense, and also the other answers were right as well, as i was using iPython but than only affected the len of locals and globals. One thing though, why do you say the list comprehension needs to be removed the keys() of globals() i run it with the two versions and the result is the same. That only states that your version is more efficient but it serves the purpose, right?

Comment: @Berenlut Yeah, I just have OCD regarding programming. Yours works fine, just the call to `keys` is not necessary because the `in` operater against a dictionary checks for `keys`. It is to do with efficiency, yes- but yours will work as well. :)

Comment: And your OCD is greatly appreciated as now i know something i didn't already knew, thanks a lot, you saved me the asking, as that was going to be my next comment... why? :D

Answer (score 2):

At the module level, `locals() == globals()`.

You are using iPython.  It adds things to `globals` as you go.

```
len(locals().keys())
Out[4]: 27

len(locals().keys())
Out[5]: 29

len(locals().keys())
Out[6]: 31

len(locals().keys())
Out[7]: 33
```

Your list comp is evaluated all at once, so there is no time for ipython to inject things into `globals()`.  If you execute it on different lines you would see:

```
s = locals().keys()

set(locals().keys()) - set(s)
Out[2]: set(['s', '_i2'])
```

Answer (score 0):

You're probably using iPython. Try running it on the Python interpreter or on a script and that behavior will disappear.

Comment: Actually it didn't disspeared. iPython did add more to locals but the cause was the answer marked as correct.